# Remove addresses with only a country

Tags: 7

For a site I am working on I am using the address field. Each node can have multiple addresses and at least one is required. All the addresses are in the US so I set the default to the US.

When the user enters and address a new field shows up with the default country address. Whenever the go to edit the page a new one with just the country is also their. They save and soon there is a bunch of addresses with only a country. This causes other parts of the site to break.

I need a way to either make the default in the form none or to delete addresses that have only a country when the node is saved/updated.

I didn't have luck with either but admitably I am new to using hooks. Below is my most recent attempt by using the node presave hook.

```
function postal_default_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'micro_property') {
    foreach($node->field_micro_address[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $address){
        dpm($address);
        unset($address['country']);
        unset($address['element_key']);
        $found = false;
        // Cycles all submitted address field components for the country to see if any have been filled
        foreach ($address as $value) {
            if (!empty($value) > 0) { $found = true; }
        }
        // Empty the address and location arrays if the fields were blank
        if (!$found) {
            dpm('not found reseting');
            $node->field_address = array();
            $node->field_location = array();
        }
    }
    return $node;
  }
}
```

The dpm messages are posting what I would expect but the node being saved is not.

Answer (score 1):

I was on the right track and made a really stupid mistake and don't know why I didn't notice it. I was deleting the correct way but I was deleting the wrong thing. I was in a loop since there are multiple addresses.

```
// Empty the address and location arrays if the fields were blank
if (!$found) {
    unset($node->field_micro_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][$k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code to delete the fields content is wrong. Have a look at: http://fooninja.net/2011/06/06/updating-nodes-programmatically-in-drupal-7/

In that blog post they use `unset()`:

```
// Delete field with index 0
unset($node->field_textfoo[$node->language][0]);

// Delete third field from a multi-value field
unset($node->field_textfoo[$node->language][2]);

// Delete whole field (if field is multi-value, all values are deleted)
unset($node->field_textfoo[$node->language]);
```

Comment: unset should work just the same as an empty array although `null !== array` drupal doesn't check. the real issue was that I wasn't deleting the right var.